# How to open second container in Flutter when I click on IconButton?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I added `Row` `widget` with rendering on `stack` `widget`. I actually want to add more `container`,  but it shows when I click on `IconButton`. After clicking it does not shows on screen. So how is possible in `Flutter` ?

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: You can use AnimatedSwitcher class to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a stack widget and when the IconButton is pressed you call a function to display the new container( which probably is inside the stack widget you are going to implement)

Comment: I added this in stack widget. but i want to actually want to add this type of funcyionality.